# Howto refactor call to new into method call with parameters?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have this code here:

```
assertThat( new Whatever(TestPerson.class, ReadOnly.class) .foo(), is(bar));
```

in a unit test. I figured that I will need multiple different such calls, which only differ in the second argument. So I thought to create a helper method so that I can do

```
assertThat( makeFor(ReadOnly.class) .foo(), is(bar));
```

I wanted to use the refactoring capabilities of IntelliJ for that, but when select `new Whatever.... .class)` and go for *Extract method* both parameters will be "hardcoded" within the the generated method. But I want only the first parameter to be hardcoded, and the second one to be a parameter for the new method.

Now I am wondering: is there an elegant way to do that with some magic IntelliJ refactoring actions? Without me manually adding the parameter after extracting that method?

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine two refactoring actions and learning different combination is the key to save and fast refactoring.

Two different combinations comes into my mind:

1. You use the `extract method` (`alt+ctrl+m`) refactoring and after you have extracted that method you select the `ReadOnly.class` use the `extract parameter` (`alt+ctrl+p`) refactoring.
2. You extract `ReadOnly.class` as a variable via `extract variable` (`alt+ctrl+v`) refactroing. Then you select the `new Wahtever(...` code and use `extract method` (`alt+ctrl+m`) and finally you select the extracted variable and use `inline variable` (`alt+ctrl+n`).

When using the 1. workflow you have the chance that Intellij Idea will detect the duplicates and suggests a signature change and will extract the other methods as well. That depends on how similar the method calls are.

BTW: That's the knowledge to unleash the power of you IDE. I guess, that I type less then half of my code. The rest is generated by refactoring actions and generators.

Example:

`null` check via postfix completion:

```
someObject.null <tab>
```

will result in:

```
if (someObject != null) {
    <CURSOR>
}
```

[Live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) are another way to store same code patterns in an executable way.